Power sum of equi-spaced cosines
My question is to prove the following identity holds for all $n,k\in\mathbb N$ and $\tau\in\mathbb C$.
$$\tag1\label1
\sum _{j=1}^{n} \cos ^k\left(\frac{2 \pi  j+\tau }{n}\right)=\frac{n}{2^k}\sum_{\substack{-\frac kn\le j\le\frac kn\\2| k+jn}} \cos(j \tau )  \binom{k}{\frac{k+jn}2}
$$
where $j\in\Bbb Z$.

My attempt: If $n$ is even,
Since $2|n$, the condition $2|k+jn$ reduces to $2|k$.
When $k$ is odd, right-hand side is $0$.
When $k$ is even, using $\cos(x)=-\cos(\pi+x)$, divide \eqref{1} by $2$
$$\tag2\label2
\sum _{j=1}^{n/2} \cos ^k\left(\frac{2 \pi  j+\tau }{n}\right)=\frac{n}{2^{k+1}}\sum_{-\frac kn\le j\le\frac kn} \cos(j \tau )  \binom{k}{\frac{k+jn}2}
$$
For $\tau=-\pi$, I know that $\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi  j-\pi}{n}\right),j=1,\dots,\frac n2$ are all roots of Chebyshev polynomial $T_{n/2}$ and it is the characteristic polynomial of
$$\mathbf A=-\frac12\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \ddots & 1 & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
The $k$-th power sum of the roots equal the trace of ${\bf A}^k$.
I don't know how to proceed.

To verify the above for $n=6,k=6,\tau=-\pi$,
WA calculation of the left side of \eqref{2}:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{6/2} \cos^6\left(\frac{2 \pi j-\pi}6\right)=\frac{27}{32}
$$
WA calculation of the right side of \eqref{2}:
$$
\frac{n}{2^{k+1}}\sum_{-\frac kn\le j\le\frac kn} \cos(j \tau )  \binom{k}{\frac{k+jn}2}=\frac{6 }{2^{6+1}}\sum_{-\frac66\le j\le\frac66} \cos (j\pi)\left(\begin{array}{c}
6 \\
\frac{6 j+6}{2}
\end{array}\right) =\frac{27}{32}
$$
WA calculation of the trace of ${\bf A}^k$
$$
\operatorname{Tr}\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{lll}
0 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\right]^6=\frac{27}{32}
$$
WA calculation of $k$-th power sum of roots of $T_{n/2}$
$$
\sum_{\left\{\omega:-3 \omega+4 \omega^3=0\right\}} \omega^6=\frac{27}{32}
$$

Have you tried expressing the cosines in terms of complex exponentials?

@RobertIsrael here power $k$ is fixed and angle $j$ is changing.

I have figured it out! I will write an answer.

Is τ a constant in this equation? don't use WA to solve trigonometry because Khan academy is better.

@fwc It is an identity that holds for all $τ\in\Bbb C$.

Lemma
$n,\tau$ are as above.
$a\in\Bbb Z,$ and $n\nmid a$, then
$$\sum _{m=1}^{n} \cos\left(a\frac{2 \pi m+\tau}{n}\right)=0$$
Proof of lemma: Expressing the cosines in terms of complex exponentials, $\ldots$

Proof of $(1)$
(In summary, by the below formula we can reduce the power $k$ to $1$, by the lemma we see many terms vanish, and the remaining part is the desired formula.)
By Power-reduction formulae:

If $n$ is even,
$$\cos^n(\theta) = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \left[\sum_{0\le r<\frac n2} \binom{n}{r} \cos \big( (n-2r)\theta \big) \right] + \frac{1}{2^n} \binom{n}{n/2}\label3\tag3$$
If $n$ is odd,
$$\cos^n(\theta) = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \left[ \sum_{0\le r<\frac n2} \binom{n}{r} \cos \big( (n-2r)\theta \big) \right]\label4\tag4$$

If $k$ is odd, substituting \eqref{4} $\cos^k(θ)$ into left side of $(1)$
$$
\sum _{j=1}^{n} \cos ^k\left(\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right)=\frac1{2^{k-1}}\sum _{m=1}^{n}\left[\sum_{0\le r<\frac k2} \binom{k}{r} \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right) \right]
$$
Exchanging summation
$$\tag6\label6
\sum _{j=1}^{n} \cos ^k\left(\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right)=\frac1{2^{k-1}}\sum_{0\le r<\frac k2}\binom{k}{r}\sum _{m=1}^{n}  \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right)
$$
If $n\nmid(k-2r)$, we have $\sin\left((k-2r)\frac\pi n\right)\ne0$.
By the lemma we have $\displaystyle\sum _{m=1}^{n}  \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right)=0$.
So we remove those $r$ such that $n\nmid(k-2r)$ in \eqref{6}:
$$
\sum _{m=1}^{n} \cos ^k\left(\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right)=\frac1{2^{k-1}}\sum_{\substack{0\le r<\frac k2\\n|k-2r}}\binom{k}{r}\sum _{m=1}^{n}  \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right)
$$
Since $n|k-2r$ we have $\cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right)=\cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{\tau }{n}\right)$ for all $m$
$$
\sum _{m=1}^{n} \cos ^k\left(\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right)=\frac1{2^{k-1}}\sum_{\substack{0\le r<\frac k2\\n|k-2r}}\binom{k}{r}n \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{\tau }{n}\right)
$$
Note that $\binom{k}{r}n \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{\tau }{n}\right)$ is the same if $r$ is replaced with $k-r$. So
$$\sum_{\substack{0\le r<\frac k2\\n|k-2r}}\binom{k}{r}n \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{\tau }{n}\right)=\sum_{\substack{\frac k2<r\le k\\n|k-2r}}\binom{k}{r}n \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{\tau }{n}\right)$$
Since $k$ is odd, $r\ne\frac{k}2$, we can merge the ranges $0\le r<\frac k2$ and $\frac k2<r\le k$ into $0\le r\le k$
then divide by $2$:
$$
\sum _{m=1}^{n} \cos ^k\left(\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right)=\frac1{2^k}\sum_{\substack{0\le r\le k\\n|k-2r}}\binom{k}{r}n \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{\tau }{n}\right)
$$
Reindex the sum with $j=\frac{k-2r}n$, we get $(1)$.

If $k$ is even, substituting \eqref{3} $\cos^k(θ)$ into left side of $(1)$
$$
\sum _{j=1}^{n} \cos ^k\left(\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right)=\left[\frac1{2^{k-1}}\sum _{m=1}^{n}\sum_{0\le r<\frac k2}\binom{k}{r} \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right) \right]+\frac{n}{2^k}\binom{k}{k/2}
$$
By the lemma, we can remove those $r$ such that $n\nmid(k-2r)$:
$$
\sum _{j=1}^{n} \cos ^k\left(\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right)=\left[\frac1{2^{k-1}}\sum _{m=1}^{n}\sum_{\substack{0\le r<\frac k2\\n|k-2r}} \binom{k}{r} \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right) \right]+\frac{n}{2^k}\binom{k}{k/2}
$$
Since $n|k-2r$ we have $\cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right)=\cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{\tau }{n}\right)$ for all $m$
$$
\sum _{m=1}^{n} \cos ^k\left(\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right)=\left[\frac1{2^{k-1}}\sum_{\substack{0\le r<\frac k2\\n|k-2r}}\binom{k}{r}n \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{\tau }{n}\right)\right]+\frac{n}{2^k}\binom{k}{k/2}
$$
Note that $\binom{k}{r}n \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{\tau }{n}\right)$ is the same if $r$ is replaced with $k-r$. So
$$\sum_{\substack{0\le r<\frac k2\\n|k-2r}}\binom{k}{r}n \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{\tau }{n}\right)=\sum_{\substack{\frac k2<r\le k\\n|k-2r}}\binom{k}{r}n \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{\tau }{n}\right)$$
We can merge the ranges $0\le r<\frac k2$ and $\frac k2<r\le k$ into $0\le r\le k,r\ne\frac{k}2$
then divide by $2$:
$$
\sum _{m=1}^{n} \cos ^k\left(\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right)=\left[\frac1{2^k}\sum_{\substack{0\le r\le k,r\ne\frac{k}2\\n|k-2r}}\binom{k}{r}n \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{\tau }{n}\right)\right]+\frac{n}{2^k}\binom{k}{k/2}
$$
The last term is equal to $\frac1{2^k}\binom{k}{r}n \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{\tau }{n}\right)$ for $r=\frac{k}2$, so we can merge it into the sum:
$$
\sum _{m=1}^{n} \cos ^k\left(\frac{2 \pi  m+\tau }{n}\right)=\frac1{2^k}\sum_{\substack{0\le r\le k\\n|k-2r}}\binom{k}{r}n \cos \left( (k-2r)\frac{\tau }{n}\right)
$$
Reindex the sum with $j=\frac{k-2r}n$, we get $(1)$.
